Does a single-photon spread while propagating?
Assume a single-photon propagates along z in a glass fiber that terminates, creating an interface glass-vacuum. After a certain length in vacuum we have a photon detector array that gives the (x,y) position of detection and the photon count (as far as I know such a device exists, e.g. from Hamamatsu). All this experiment is in a very dark environment and of course in vacuum.
In the fiber we can be confident that the photon is confined in the circle -3<x<3um, -3<y<3um, where this size is realistic for a 6um core diameter. After the fiber we do not know what happens, but the detector tells that the atom of the detector material absorbing the photon can be in a much bigger circle in the (x,y) plane. We call this spread in localization a diffraction. We repeat the experiment many times and are able to quantify that the single-photon is detected in a much bigger circle with radius r=R.
In principle, after this result, one can have two possible interpretations of what happens in vacuum:

The single-photon is very localized around a propagation direction, maybe not more than the pixel size, it just changes its direction of propagation when exiting the fiber core. The new direction has some randomness.
The single-photon is spreading during propagation so much that when impinging the camera it covers the entire region of radius R. Then why the atom A at r=0 rather than the atom B at r=R is absorbing it, is purely random.

Question 1: is there an experiment that can confirm one or exclude one or both of these pictures?
Question 2: is there an experiment that clarifies how extended in space in vacuum is a single-photon? Has the size of an electron, of an atom, of 10^n atoms?
Note: I do not want answers based on theories, quantum or non-quantum. I want a published experiment if any.

A photon is just a small amount of energy. It's not a packet of energy that can be subdivided further. We can't observe a quarter photon here and three quarters over there. How many photons an absorbing surface or volume will absorb on average can be calculated with classical intensities (Maxwell). You don't even need a published experiment. Every time you see something with your own eyes this is what happens. The only intuitive problem here is the idea that there is something "below" the level of photons. There isn't.

@FlatterMann That the energy of a single-photon (energy quantum) is the lowest possible for a specific optical frequency is a well known fact. But this does not have any obvious implication on the spatial extension of this physical thing ortogonally to the propagation direction. Has the size of an electron, of an atom, of 10^n atoms? What the experimental physics says about this question?

Energy is the ability of a system to perform work on another system. It's a system property. When did we ever claim or teach that system properties have size and position? What you are calling size here is the size of the detector (measurement system). That has absolutely nothing to do with the energy that it detects. I can detect the same amount of  energy with one atom or with a dinner plate. Nothing changes about the energy.

@FlatterMann If you define a photon as a quantum of energy of the electromagnetic field, talking about position, does indeed not make sense. And when talking about a quantum particle of such sharply defined energy, it indeed would be delocalized across the entire space unless confined by some potential. However, when op talks about photons from my understanding he seems to just mean a quantum particle, that has a wave function with some small spread in momentum, energy and space.

The question as I understand it then would be, if there is a way to determine, whether measurement deviations of some specific setup come from the spread of almost identical wave functions before every measurement or of different time development of different states during different measurements.

@Zaph It's not me defining it that way. It's what we measure in quantum experiments. I did not say anywhere that "the energy was sharply defined". The energy is simply what the measurement system receives from the quantum system. The problem with the way we teach quantum mechanics is that we talk about "particles that have properties". There are no particles at the phenomenological level at all. There are only property changes. An atom that is in an excited state has more energy than in the ground state. It does not have "a photon particle" attached to it.

In the case of a photon from a distant star, passing through a 'gravitationally-lensing' region to reach our telescope, surely the photon is effectively many many light years wide, or has to be thought of as that size, if we want to 'explain' its 'path'? I don't know whether the problem to intuition is just the same except for scale, or whether the nanometers to light years change in scale needs radically different thinking.

@FlatterMann I substantially agree with your viewpoint. But I would like to ask you a thing. Is there an experimental way to argue that a photon is arbitrarily “small”? It appears to be small just because we can construct arbitrarily small detectors? The fact that a detector either detects or does not detect a photon as a whole says that the photon is a single entity not that it is arbitrarily small. What is your opinion about these issues?

@ValterMoretti Energy doesn't have a size. It never had a size in classical mechanics. Why would it get a size now? How "localized" the energy in my detector is depends solely on the size of my detector system. For a green photon that could be the size of a single atom, but I have done a student experiment in university where a microwave photon's worth of energy flipped a nuclear spin which was coupled to a meta-stable electronic state. That state decayed and released an optical photon, which was then detected with a PMT. Did I localize the microwave photon down to the size of a nucleus?

Ok, that is the answer I expected to receive. And do you agree that roughly speaking  "there is no way to simultaneously detect a single photon into two detectors". Can you elaborate this fact if you agree? I would like to have a more precise idea about ",localization".

@ValterMoretti Maybe. Can we go smaller than that? Not with any experimental hardware I have ever seen. Can you give me something that's smaller than a nucleus that is, in some meaningful way, localized in space? Below the level of nuclei in solids everything becomes a free field as far as I can tell. So, yeah, we can pretend that a 1GeV electron beam localizes green photons to the deBroglie wavelength of the electrons in a scattering experiment, but does it really? What does that mean?

I agree with you

@ValterMoretti Energy is a singleton because it is locally conserved. We don't teach in classical physics either that one can use the same 1 Joule to lift a weight in one end of the experiment and to compress a spring in the other. I can either lift the weight with that 1J or I can compress the spring, but not do both by 1J. That would violate energy conservation. To me that is didactically a very simple phenomenon to explain. The actual conservation law at work here is angular momentum conservation, of course. What is quantized is not actually the energy of the photon but its spin.

Clear, I have something to think about, thanks.

My pleasure. I have come to believe that most of the difficulties that students have with quantum mechanics are caused by poor language choices from the early 1900s. The math and the structure of the theory are all crystal clear, but the way we talk about it is very messy. Take care.

@FlatterMann these are few examples from eminent scientists. A. Einstein "According to a point of view to be considered here, when a light ray radiates outward from a point, its energy does not spread out evenly over larger volume, but rather consists of a finite number of spatially localized energy quanta, which move without dividing, and which can only be absorbed and produced as whole" in On a Heuristic Point of View Concerning the Production and Transformation of Light (1905).

P.A.M. Dirac. "These particles, which are called photons, have each a definite energy and momentum, depending on the frequency of the light, and appear to have just as real an existence as electrons, or any other particles known in physics." The Principles of Quantum Mechanics (1930).
A. Einstein "All the fifty years of conscious brooding have brought me no closer to the answer to the question: What are light quanta?. Of course today every rascal thinks he knows the answer, but he is deluding himself." (1951)

A. Einstein "All the fifty years of conscious brooding have brought me no closer to the answer to the question: What are light quanta?. Of course today every rascal thinks he knows the answer, but he is deluding himself." (1951)
R. Feynman: "I'm telling you the way it [light] behave - like particles" "..every instrument that has been designed to be sensitive enough to detect weak light has always ended up discovering the same thing: light is made of particles" in QED The strange theory of light and matter (1985).

P. Grangier, G. Roger and A. Aspect: "They illustrate the wave-particle duality of light" in Experimental Evidence for a Photon Anticorrelation Effect on
a Beam Splitter: A New Light on Single-Photon Interferences (1986).
W.E. Lamb: "Radiation does not consist of particles..." in Anti-photon (1995).
Less eminent but directly affecting students: T. L. Dimitrova A. Weis in The wave-particle duality of light: A demonstration experiment (2007).
However I agree with you that the spatial extension of the quanta is just arbitrary depending on what tool is used to measure it.

@Ang Science is not the collection of opinions of eminent scientists. Science is the rational description of nature. Such a rational description can be summarized in the following: 1) Quanta are small amounts of energy, momentum, angular momentum and charge. 2) Energy, momentum, angular momentum and charge are system properties. 3) System properties belong to systems and do not have spatial location and extent. They are observer dependent. One can do quantum mechanics without wave-particle duality and that is what the formalism does.

@FlatterMann I just wanted to show some examples of what you called ”poor language choices from the early 1900s.” And that students are still today fooled with this wave-particle duality arguments. Well to me seemed more than poor language choices, rather seem wrong statements (except what W. Lamb states). Anyway, those statements are problematic as we have discussed here, in this very helpful discussion.

@Ang I see your point. Yes, individual scientists did make false statements about quantum mechanics. You can start with Einstein's actual biggest blunder in his photoelectric paper in which he tries to identify photons as Newtonian corpuscles. My point is that if you check the average quantum mechanics textbook, then the formalism is correct (at least up to occasional mistakes). It's the language that comes with the formalism that is confusing. That we are still talking about energy as "a particle" 124 years after knowing better is a problem similar to phlogiston and aether.

All received answers contain some crucial aspects. I try to compile a single answer containing all these aspects.
When we change the apparatus, the probability of the photons being absorbed in a certain point in space changes. So we'll have different macroscopic/collective patterns depending on the apparatus characteristics. It appears that the way how energy flows through the apparatus depends on the apparatus.
Question 1: is there an experiment that can confirm one or exclude one or both of these pictures?
Answer: No, what happens between the source (the fiber-vacuum interface) and the detector is not possible to be disclosed directly. If one count is recorded by the instrument we can state that the energy quantum was transferred to the detector. We can state that the transfer of energy happened in one specific pixel in the detector array. We could move the detector at differnt distances z from the end of the fiber with the intention to trace a trajectory of the photon. But this cannot be done because we do not have any possibility to guarantee that the next photon will be an exact copy of the previous one.
Question 2: is there an experiment that clarifies how extended in space in vacuum is a single-photon? Has the size of an electron, of an atom, of 10^n atoms?
Answer: No, there isn’t. It seems obvious to represent the photon as something that has the size comparable to the electron cloud of the atom absorbing it. But it is really arbitrary how we want to picture that. It can be pictured as a ball with the size of a pixel but also as something that extends over the entire detection area and then the absorbing process happens with a certain probability distribution in a specific point $(x_0, y_0)$. Depending on what kind of apparatus we use to localize where the absorption process happens, we get different results, therefore the extension of a quantum is just an arbitrary property or, in other words, not a property of the quantum.

The "photon" has the same extent as a classical EM wave passing through the same apparatus.

@Jagerber48 if you edit your answer and add great level of details or link an article that proves your statement I will be happy to delete my answer and accept yours instead.

I've expanded my answer. Think about doing a Young's double slit experiment with the output of the fiber.

@Jagerber48 A photon is an amount of energy, momentum and angular momentum. These are system properties. System properties don't have "extent". They didn't have that in classical mechanics, either. A classical EM wave is an approximation of many photons, IF they form a suitable classical state. If they don't, then there is no classical EM wave that can describe the physics of that particular experiment correctly.

@Flatterman Classically, and quantum mechanically, the momentum and angular momentum of the electromagnetic field are spatially varying.

@Jagerber48 There is no such thing as an "electromagnetic field" in quantum mechanics. The electromagnetic field is merely the mean field theory of quantum electrodynamics. It's the lowest order approximation among an infinite number of correlation functions needed to describe the actual physics of the electromagnetic quantum field correctly.

@FlatterMann "There is no such thing as an "electromagnetic field" In quantum mechanics" that sounds like a fringe point of view. Quantization of the electromagnetic field (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantization_of_the_electromagnetic_field) is a standard part of an upper undergraduate or graduate curriculum in quantum mechanics.

@Jagerber48 Quantization is always an ad-hoc guess that gets us from the mean field theory to the full theory. If we guess correctly (as Feynman, Schwinger and Tomonaga did in 1949, if I remember correctly), then we get a quantum field theory. That doesn't mean that the mean field theory is a good representation of the full theory. It never is.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Both these situations are actually the same situation, just different ways of interpreting it. You don't really need a "published experiment" here because what happens is well known as a consequence of basic quantum theory.
Consider a single-mode fiber. Here, by definition, inside the fiber there is only one mode of propagation, and thus the photon can only be moving in one direction at any time: the direction along the length of the fiber.
Once outside the fiber, the wavefunction of the photon spreads out. Note: this does not mean the photon chooses a direction randomly. There is no randomness here, yet. The wavefunction (in the position basis) expands deterministically.   The system enters a state of superposition, where the photon is in a superposition of being in different places with some probability amplitude.
Once the light hits the detector, there is no randomness either, yet. The system merely enters the state where all the sensors in the array are in a superposition of being activated or not activated.
Now, observation. According to the collapse postulate, when you actually measure which photodetector was activated, you will measure one out of the many detectors being activated, and all other detectors not being activated. Exactly which detector you measure as being activated is random.
However, let's say that instead of photodetectors, you have an array of direction sensors, which tell you the angle of incidence of the photon once they hit the detector, but don't tell you anything about the spatial position of the photon. In this case, you would measure the photon randomly taking one direction out of many possible directions, once it exited the fiber.
You could repeat this experiment with either the spatial position detector or angle of incidence detector placed at any point distant from the fiber exit, and the results would be the same.
Ultimately, this is basically the same kind of experiment as the double-slit experiment. Depending on where you measure the photon and what you measure, different variables appear 'random'. But this is just because of how measurement works.

You focus on the case where the photons wave function propagates unitarily. When thinking of the systems wave function, that might be true in general. How ever when trying to model the behavior with a single photons wave function there is the possibility of it getting perturbed by some unknown factors while propagating. Partial-tracing back to the single photons wave function would then destroy unitarity and one might think, that that might be what OP meant with his description of case 1. In that case it would be wrong to say that both are only different interpretations of the same thing.

OP said it propagates in vacuum. What unknown factors could perturb it?

Well he asked for explicit experimental setups, so taking the possibility of non ideal effects due to limited experimental capabilities into account just seemed reasonable to me. What do I know what kind of interactions might realistically happen, when the wave leaves the fiber.

@Zaph The wave function does not belong to either the photon (which is a small amount of energy) or the system. It's a description of the ensemble of the system. Since ensembles are purely abstract/hypothetical constructs of the human mind, there can be no wave functions in nature. You can find foundational papers that derive wave functions from Kolmogorov's axioms for independent sampling. Unitarity and linearity of quantum mechanics follow directly from these axioms, which in mathematical terms are essentially just a special class of partitions of unity.

No such experiment has been done and I've read a lot of papers and experimented with many fibres/cameras/lasers.  It is not a practical experiment ... theory says we can't measure a photon without destroying it ...so its not possible.
At the exit of the fiber there is a strong interaction of the EM field of space, the fiber end and the photon, i.e. all the electron motion in these materials and in the entire apparatus are random and contribute to the EM field... this is the essence of diffraction.
The other issue is no matter how small your fiber the photon will enter based on probability .... again the EM field rules all .... the smaller the hole the lower the probability. You can google weak measurement and/or weak interaction for photons ... this is a good method to get an idea of photon behaviour but it is indeed statistical.

Disclaimer
I know you explicitly said, you don’t want theory based answers. But I find the question interesting and would like to share my thoughts on it anyways. Feel free to just ignore it, if you are not interested in this answer.
On my understanding of the Question
The problem is, as you might well know, that the moment you measure the a particle it will collapse into in eigenstate of the corresponding observable. At that point all the information about the previous state of the particle is gone except, that it had some component of the eigenstate you measured. That means not only can’t you measure the path the evolution of a particles wave function took, you can’t even determine the wave function of the particle. The only thing you can do is try to prepare a lot of particles in very similar states, then measure each of them and try to reconstruct the probability density of that state, form you measurements.
So from that background I do understand your question in the following way: Is there a way to determine, whether the deviations of your repeated experiments do come from very similar quantum states, that just spread during unitary time evolution, or whether your setup is producing very different quantum states, that develop into very different states even before measuring. So to speak check if your measurement deviations are from quantum-uncertainty-effects or just artifacts of your setup.
My first idea of a procedure
I think one thing one could do, is use some optical grid to create an interference pattern behind your setup. If you do create almost the same state in every measurement repeating the measurement often should yield the intensity profile expected behind the grid for a coherent light experiment. If you however create different states after leaving the fiber, I would expect you to just see some unstructured spread, as the interference patterns of you probability densities would differ every time you measure and therefore not converge to a pattern.
My second idea of a procedure
One could try creating an entangled pair of photons and send each of them threw one of your described setups. If your setup only includes unitary time evolution (including the expected spreading of your wave-function after leaving the fiber), you would then expect perfect correlation of the directions your particles take due to momentum conservation. If however your state gets perturbed when leaving the fiber, such correlations should be destroyed.

Unitary time evolution simply means that the number of ensemble members in our ensemble doesn't change. There is no deeper physical meaning to it than that. It doesn't tell us anything about the individual measurement. The measurement itself is the transfer of a quantum of energy from the quantum system to the measurement system. There is no such thing as "collapse". It is energy flowing from one system to another. There is no great mystery behind it than that, either. What confuses people about quantum mechanics is the "abstract state" notion when it's actually all about energy flow.

@FlatterMann When describing Quantum mechanics theoretically, we do use wave functions developing unitarily (,which means more then just perservation of the number of different states in ones ensemble). Now its true that we can’t measure them directly, but assuming they exist (and collapse) is still what gives us the best predictions of the real measurements. I see no use in claiming they are not a real thing.

I have never measured a state. I have measured quanta of energy, momentum, angular momentum and charge. One has to differentiate between the abstract bookkeeping of the purely theoretical ensemble state and actual physics, which are these individual energy, momentum, angular momentum and charge exchanges. There is no need to insert something like "collapse" between the two. Quanta are real, quantum mechanical state is the law of large numbers limit of actual frequentist histograms. Would you call a histogram (a table on paper) part of nature? A wavefunction is even less real than that table.

Please resist the urge to think of photons as particles. Photons are quantized excitations of spatial modes of the electromagnetic field.
When thinking about these kinds of questions always think about the classical EM field explanation first. In the classical EM field we have a wave guided along by the fiber. When it exits the fiber the mode couples out of the fiber and into free space so it rapidly diffracts. If you put a detector or a screen some distance from the fiber tip you will see an approximately Gaussian spot on the detector/screen. Now if you turn the power propagating through the fiber lower and lower and you make sure your detector is a pixel array of single photon detectors, you will start to see the pixels only light up one at a time. But if you wait very long and plot the distribution of photons counted you will see the distribution matches the classical mode profile.
The fact that we continuously tune from the classical EM wave picture to the "photon" picture makes me start to think the photon is spreading out, it is not "localized but travelling in a random direction". But we can come up with an experiment that lends even more credence to this point of view.
Back to classical EM picture. We have the fiber and we have light propagating down it and exiting. Now instead of placing a screen some distance from the fiber we place instead two new fiber inputs.
                           \  \  \   \ >---- New Fiber 1 Input
Original Fiber Output ----< |  |  |  |   
                           /  /  /   / >---- New Fiber 2 Input

Now take the outputs of the two fibers and combine them on a beamsplitter. and look at one or both of the outputs. Also arrange the ability to precisely tune (to sub-wavelength precision) the distance between one of the fiber outputs and the beamsplitter.
                             Detector 1 
                                 |
                                 |
                                 |
                                 o

                                 
New Fiber 1 Output ----<         /     o--- Detector 2


                                 v
                                 |
                                 |
                           New Fiber 2 Output

As you tune the distance between one of the fiber outputs and the splitter you will see interference fringes on the two detectors. Recall this is a classical experiment.
Now turn down the light so you are back in the single photon regime. If, in the classical experiment, you were on a dark fringe on detector one and a bright fringe on detector two, you will never see a photon detected on detector one and you will always see one on detector two.
This says there is spatial coherence between the output of the first fiber at the locations of the inputs of the latter two fibers. In my mind this ruins the theory that the photon is localized but travelling in a specific but random direction. At LEAST, given this analog of the Young's double slit experiment, you have to allow that the "localized" bullets of light (I really dislike viewing it this way) travel along multiple paths at once. But at this point just admit it's a quantized electromagnetic field.

Ok, finally after writing this answer, I embarrassingly realize that it would be much simpler to just put a double slit at the output of the fiber and observe the direct Young's double slit interference pattern. First classically with bright light, but then quantum mechanically as the light level is turned down. This question is asking exactly the question which is answered by Young's double slit experiment. The answer is that the photon "interferes" with itself. So we cannot just think of it as a particle travelling in a random direction. There is necessarily more to the theory than that. For me it is best explained by thinking of photons as being quantized excitations of spatial modes of the electromagnetic field. With emphasis on the field nature of the EM field.

Nice answer (+1) Could you elaborate on just the statement "when it exits the fiber the mode couples out of the fiber and into free space so it rapidly diffracts", please? This seems contrary to my intuition about light. E.g. A beam of laser light will travel pretty much in a straight path without diffraction in free space, right? Light rays in from sunlight, torches, etc. also do not seem to diffract as they travel in free space...

‘Photons are quantized excitations of spatial modes of the electromagnetic field.’ How does that differ from any other quantum particle?

@James Look up Gaussian beams. it is impossible to have a "column" of light propagating through free space with a fixed radius. For "typical" beams, the closest thing we have is a Gaussian beam. The beam has a point in space along its axis where it is smallest (the waist) and it spread out from there. If the waist is large compared to its wavelength the spreading is modest, but if the waist is small, like at the output of a single-mode fiber, the spreading is aggressive. One can quarrel over whether to call this effect "diffraction". The point is it is a result of the wave equation (1/2)

Satisfied by EM fields (2/2).

@my2cts Yes, my understanding is that all quantum "particles" are quantized excitations in the corresponding field. I am trying to specifically contrast this with the classical view of a particle as a billiard ball, or even the quantum view of a non-relativistic particle as a quantum billiard ball. Something localized but with probabilistic position and momentum. I think the word "particle", in this case, is regrettable when it is really the field nature which matters.

@Jagerber48 That is an often repeated semi-classical viewpoint, but it is not useful to do real quantum mechanics. What people call "particles" are quanta of energy, momentum, angular momentum and charge. These properties are being exchanged irreversibly between physical systems. Quantum mechanics describes the statistical averages of an infinite number of such energy exchanges in hypothetical ensembles of systems. So neither the particle nor the field/wave picture are all that helpful here. You have to get used to thinking in statistical properties of energy exchanges in ensembles.

@FlatterMann It's not clear, mathematically rigorously, what "quanta of energy, momentum, and charge" are. The "exchanges" you are talking about are related to the local energy exchanges between two or more (quantum) fields. The fields are infinite in extent, but the interactions between fields are local. This means for field A and field B to interact they need to have appreciable amplitude in the same region of spacetime. So yes, interactions are local. But that doesn't mean the field is made up of "particles".

@Jagerber48 It is experimentally completely clear what that means. Charge quantization can be seen in the Millikan experiment. Energy quantization are behind Planck radiation and the photoelectric effect and angular momentum quantization is demonstrated by e.g. a Stern-Gerlach experiment. Some theory textbook authors are not very interested in relating these quantities to actual physics because they know that there are plenty of atomic physics textbooks that do this, already. If there is a lesson here it's this: quantum mechanics is opaque without learning atomic physics in parallel.

@Jagerber48 yes, that makes sense. There is another thing that bothers me, if you could explain it as well. A wave packet of water in the pool cannot self- propagate itself in a concentrated direction, right? It disperses very quickly in all direction until nothing is left of the original wave packet's amplitude... What is different about EM waves that allows a wave packet to remain concentrated as a wave packet, while propelling itself long distance in a particular direction without dispersing away its amplitude?

@James Well what I just explained about a Gaussian beam says that a beam of light does spread away from its axis so that its amplitude is reduced as it propagates. I'm sure you can have a relatively directed water wave but both water and light waves "spread" as they propagate because of the wave equations they satisfy. So they can't carry their energy in an infinite "beam".

@Jagerber48 There seems surely a difference, though, since a water wave packet cannot travel 100 meters and remain a wave packet, don't you think? On the other hand, an EM wave packet can travel for billions of light years while remaining concentrated as a wave packet, so there must be a different dispersion mechanism between the two?

@Jagerber48 ... E.g. water waves have a single component field, while EM waves / Schrodinger waves are 2 components field which is feeding each other, right? I am still a little hazy is all what is it about having 2 components that feed each other that allows for long range propagation of wave packets...

@James please ask a separate question. Your question is about classical propagation of general waves and electromagnetic waves specifically. I'm not sure what you mean by long range propagation, but water wave packets can propagate for hundreds of miles.

@Jagerber48 thank you, i think i got the answer to this. The quantum harmonic oscillator is a demonstration of a 2 component wave packet that can remain standing indefinitely, i.e. "nondispersive wave packet / coherent state", which cannot exist in 1 component waves like water. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_harmonic_oscillator

Additional ref: https://www.researchgate.net/post/Non-dispersive-quantum-mechanical-wave-packets "In free space (i.e. no forces, no barriers), all wave functions disperse. If forces are allowed to be present, the ground state of a harmonic oscillator is non-dispersive (as are all eigenstates of any spatially bounded system)."

@James this is totally off topic. Please ask a separate question.

Alright, thank you for discussing this with me
